# Moment of Inertia of a Triangular Lamina with Vertices at the Origin, $P$ and $Q$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

Wikipedia lists the moment of inertia of a triangular lamina with vertices at the origin, $P$, $Q$ (position vectors) as $m(PP+PQ+QQ)/6$. However, it seems there is no derivation of this formula available anywhere! I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through the path to the result.

Comment: Can you link the wiki page, please? I need to understand if this is a 3D or a 2D problem. If $P$ and $Q$ are vectors, is $P Q$ really the dot product $P \cdot Q$ or something else?

Comment: [Related SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618980/380384) where `mmoi = 1/6*mass*( a·a + b·b + c·c + a·b + b·c + c·a )` and in your case `c=0` the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to derive it.

1. Parametrize the interior of the triangle with

   $$ \boldsymbol{\rm pos}(t,u)  = t (1-u) \boldsymbol{P} + t\, u\, \boldsymbol{Q} $$

   with $t=0 \ldots 1$ and $u=0\ldots1$.
2. Find the unit area

   $$ {\rm d}A=\|\left(\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{\rm pos}}{\partial t}\times\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{\rm pos }}{\partial u}\right)\|{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u =t\, \| \boldsymbol{P} \times \boldsymbol{Q} \|\;{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u$$
3. Find the triangle area, volume (assume infinitesimal thickness $w$) and mass
   $$ A = \frac{1}{2} \| \boldsymbol{P} \times \boldsymbol{Q} \| $$

$$ V = \frac{w}{2} \| \boldsymbol{P} \times \boldsymbol{Q} \| $$

$$ m = \frac{\rho w}{2} \| \boldsymbol{P} \times \boldsymbol{Q} \| $$

4. Form MMOI tensor integral

   $$ \mathbf{I}_0 = 2 m \int \int \left( - [\boldsymbol{\rm pos}\times] [\boldsymbol{\rm pos}\times] \right)  t\, {\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u $$

   where the $[\boldsymbol{r}\times]$ notation for a vector [represents a 3×3 matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) such that $[\boldsymbol{r}\times] \boldsymbol{g} = \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{g}$ for any $\boldsymbol{g}$. Here were are retaining this notation and carrying through the manipulations in order to see what we end up with in the end.

   $$ [\boldsymbol{\rm pos} \times]  = t (1-u) [\boldsymbol{P} \times] + t\, u\, [\boldsymbol{Q} \times] $$

   $$ \begin{aligned}\mathbf{I}_{0} & =2m\iint \left(-[\boldsymbol{{\rm pos}}\times][\boldsymbol{{\rm pos}}\times]\right)t\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u \\
    & =2m\iint t^{3}  \left(-(1-u)^{2}[\boldsymbol{P}\times][\boldsymbol{P}\times]-u\,(1-u)\left([\boldsymbol{Q}\times][\boldsymbol{P}\times]+[\boldsymbol{P}\times][\boldsymbol{Q}\times]\right)-u^{2}[\boldsymbol{Q}\times][\boldsymbol{Q}\times]\right)\,{\rm d}t{\rm d}u\\
    & =2m\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{3}[\boldsymbol{P}\times][\boldsymbol{P}\times]-\frac{1}{6}\left([\boldsymbol{Q}\times][\boldsymbol{P}\times]+[\boldsymbol{P}\times][\boldsymbol{Q}\times]\right)-\frac{1}{3}[\boldsymbol{Q}\times][\boldsymbol{Q}\times]\right)\\
    & =\frac{m}{6}\left(-[\boldsymbol{P}\times][\boldsymbol{P}\times]-\frac{1}{2}[\boldsymbol{P}\times][\boldsymbol{Q}\times]-\frac{1}{2}[\boldsymbol{Q}\times][\boldsymbol{P}\times]-[\boldsymbol{Q}\times][\boldsymbol{Q}\times]\right)
   \end{aligned} $$
5. Project the problem down to **2D**

   In 2D the general terms above with the cross products can be simplified since only the out-of-plane components are of interest here

   $$ -[\boldsymbol{P}\times] [ \boldsymbol{Q} \times] = \begin{bmatrix} 
    \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\ \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & P_x Q_x + P_y Q_y \end{bmatrix} = \boldsymbol{P} \cdot \boldsymbol{Q}$$

   So the MMOI term becomes

$$ \begin{aligned}\mathbf{I}_{0}= & \frac{m}{6}\left(\boldsymbol{P}\cdot\boldsymbol{P}+\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{P}\cdot\boldsymbol{Q}+\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{Q}\cdot\boldsymbol{P}+\boldsymbol{Q}\cdot\boldsymbol{Q}\right)\\
 & = \frac{m}{6}\left(\boldsymbol{P}\cdot\boldsymbol{P}+\boldsymbol{P}\cdot\boldsymbol{Q}+\boldsymbol{Q}\cdot\boldsymbol{Q}\right)
\end{aligned} $$